# CoreAVC and Java

Tags: java, h.264, java-web-start

Is there a binding to use [CoreAVC](http://corecodec.com/products/coreavc) in Java or more specific in Java WebStart ? I need to decode h.264/AVC in Java Webstart.

Answer (score 0):

You can use http://jcodec.org/. It's pure Java and therefore it will run in a webstart environment.

Answer (score 0):

It's simple with JCodec ( http://jcodec.org ):

```
FileChannelWrapper ch = null;
try {
    ch = NIOUtils.readableFileChannel(new File("path to mp4"));
    FrameGrab frameGrab = new FrameGrab(ch);

    frameGrab.seek(351.); // important to pass double for a second
    BufferedImage frame;
    for (int i = 0; (frame = frameGrab.getFrame()) != null && i < 200; i++) {
        ImageIO.write(frame, "jpg", new File(String.format("frame%08d.png", i)));
    }
} finally {
    NIOUtils.closeQuietly(ch);
}
```